# Error when compiling node.js

Tags: node.js, compilation, makefile, installation

I downloaded the git repo from the official link,

```
git clone git://
```

and I ran `./configure && make && make install` where the `make install` returns with error:

```
  LINK(target) /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/node: Finished
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_header.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_provider.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_ustack.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_etw.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_mdb.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_perfctr.stamp
  touch /usr/local/bin/node/out/Release/obj.target/specialize_node_d.stamp
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/bin/node/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node

#make install

make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/bin/node/out'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/bin/node/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
/usr/bin/python tools/install.py install '' '/usr/local'
installing /usr/local/bin/node
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/install.py", line 202, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[:])
  File "tools/install.py", line 197, in run
    if cmd == 'install': return files(install)
  File "tools/install.py", line 130, in files
    action(['out/Release/node'], 'bin/node')
  File "tools/install.py", line 79, in install
    def install(paths, dst): map(lambda path: try_copy(path, dst), paths)
  File "tools/install.py", line 79, in <lambda>
    def install(paths, dst): map(lambda path: try_copy(path, dst), paths)
  File "tools/install.py", line 70, in try_copy
    try_unlink(target_path) # prevent ETXTBSY errors
  File "tools/install.py", line 33, in try_unlink
    os.unlink(path)
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/usr/local/bin/node'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I'm really not familiar with this, what is the issue?

I ran the commands with root, when I googled for the error, I only found permission problem topics but that not the case here.

Comment: Did you try making and installing a stable node version instead (e.g. v0.10.28)?

Comment: @mscdex problem solved by renaming/moving the source folder, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded node.js source to `/usr/local/bin/node`, node.js compiles fine to folder `/usr/local/bin/node/out` and is THEN trying to install it's link/executable to `/usr/local/bin/node` which is a folder...

```
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/usr/local/bin/node'
```

Solution:

Rename the folder `/usr/local/bin/node` (like `/usr/local/bin/node-src`) and repeat installation process.

Compiles fine:

```
giant:/usr/local/bin/node-src# l ../
total 14228
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root staff 14562901 May 26 14:12 node
drwxr-sr-x 11 root staff     4096 May 26 14:16 node-src
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff       38 May 26 14:16 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur in case you don't have prerequisite  package installled. so, try the following

**sudo apt-get -y install build-essential g++ libssl-dev pkg-config**

In case all package have already installed successfully in your system then do the following

**sudo apt-get install libc-ares2 libev4 libv8-3.7.12.22 nodejs**

after this just type

**node -v**

to check if its correctly solves your problem or not.